# strsplit excluding one, but including another

Tags: matlab

A very short question.  I have a string

```
str = 'var(:,1),var(:,2),var(:,3)';
```

I need to split it with strsplit by ',' but not by ':,' so that I will end up with a cell array

```
cel = {'var(:,1)','var(:,2)','var(:,3)'};
```

I am not good with regular expression at all and I tried ,^(:,) but this fails.  I thought ^ is not () is group.

How can it be done?

Comment: do you intend to use `eval` later on?

Comment: ^ "Anything you say may be used against you" :-D

Comment: ahahaha....(silence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression with [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
cel = regexp(str, '(?<!:),', 'split');
```